# PCE-AC88 Wifi not working after updating Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I just updated Ubuntu and now my wifi card doesn't show up and the driver will not load. It uses the **brcmfmac** driver which I have tried using **modprobe brcmfmac** with no success.

I have tried installing **firmware-b43-installer** as well as others with no success either. When I boot into a previous version, 5.15, I can load **brcmfmac** and it works, but in 5.19 it does not.

I have tracked the issue down to what I think is this, from **dmesg | grep brcm**:

```
brcmfmac 0000:0d:00.0: brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers: invalid> max_flowrings(264).
```

There is a bug report and possible fix from this [post](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216894).
I do not know how to apply the fix from that post though. I need to fix this in a few days as I need Ubuntu for school.

**Solution Found**

I manually updated the headers to 6.3 and the wifi card works on it fully updated. I can't find the original link I used but it was similar to this [install latest kernel](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/) link.

Comment: I recommend that you try a live session of Ubuntu 23.04 which uses kernel version 6.2.0-xx and see if it works. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have a same error, wifi stopped working after upgrade from 22 version. What a mess again, I am so tired of these problems on Ubuntu. Please share a solution here if you find any!

Comment: @ManicDepression Please start your own new question.

Comment: @ManicDepression found a solution, see my updated post.